# How to Interpret this PMAP output?

Tags: c, linux, unix, dynamic, posix

I have a [cat++](https://cnds.jacobs-university.de/courses/os-2019/src/cat++/) program and I am running the following command to check how many memory segments are added to the process when any one of the libraries implementing a transform is loaded.

`(echo "hello world" ; sleep 100) | ./cat++ -l ./librot13.so -l ./libupper.so -l ./librot13.so & pmap $!`

I get the following output but I am unable to interpret it. **How many memory segments are being loaded? What's happening when the same library is called twice as in my command?** Is there an alternative pmap command that I should run?

```
3847:   ./cat++ -l ./librot13.so -l ./libupper.so -l ./librot13.so
000055ec84326000      8K r-x-- cat++
000055ec84527000      4K r---- cat++
000055ec84528000      4K rw--- cat++
000055ec84ef3000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00007f07540d6000      4K r-x-- libupper.so
00007f07540d7000   2044K ----- libupper.so
00007f07542d6000      4K r---- libupper.so
00007f07542d7000      4K rw--- libupper.so
00007f07542d8000      4K r-x-- librot13.so
```

continued...

Answer (score 0):

When memory segments are created they are given permissions - read, write, and execute - or `rwx` for shorthand. In the output you are seeing, the virtual memory address of a segment is given, along with the size of that segment, the permissions of that segment, and the name (if available) of the file used to populate the segment. These are pretty standard results from something like the `mmap` command, which is often used behind the scenes by the loader to help load libraries. That is how to interpret the format of your output.

**How many memory segments are being loaded?**
Each of the files you've included appears to have a `read`/`execute` section (very common for code sections such as `.text`), a `readonly` section (common for readonly sections such as `.rodata`), and a `read`/`write` section (common for global data sections such as `.data`. For reasons generally related to security and standardization, these parts of the file are loaded into segments with different permissions. For example, you wouldn't generally want the instructions of your program to be writable (otherwise an arbitrary memory write vulnerability would allow attackers to write their own instructions in your address space).

**What's happening when the same library is called twice as in my command?**
Long story short, don't worry about multiple segments being created for an individual file. The file isn't being loaded more than once. Rather, portions of the file are being loaded based on their permissions. This is because all of the features I mentioned above.

If you want to understand the ELF file format a bit more and see how the loader knows how to create memory segments, try using the `readelf` utility on your `cat++` program. The program headers will show you the number of segments, the sections in each segment, and the permissions of each segment (and much more). Try `readelf -l cat++` and see for yourself.